# How can I create a transaction that creates an NFT when signed by the user using Metaplex?

Tags: metaplex, nft, react, transaction

I made TypeScript code where I could make an NFT using an image-link as the metadata (taking help from the Solana Stack Exchange site). Now. When I tried to implement it in my frontend, I was getting  errors.

```
const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
      .use(keypairIdentity(user))
      .use(
        bundlrStorage({
          address: "https://devnet.bundlr.network",
          providerUrl: "https://api.devnet.solana.com",
          timeout: 60000,
        })
      )
```

The problem is that in `use(keypairIdentity(user))` user is a Keypair, i.e., both the public key and private key. However, when making the frontend, I am unable to access the private key. So. I am unsure of how to go with this.

Here is the full code:

```
export const CreateNFT: FC = () =>
{
    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const { publicKey } = useWallet();
    const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
        if (!publicKey) throw new Error("No wallet connected"); // Corrected: throw a new Error object instead of WalletNotConnectedError

        // rent for token mint
        const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);

        // keypair for new token mint
        const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();

        // get metadata PDA for token mint
        const metadataPDA = await findMetadataPda(mintKeypair.publicKey);

        // get associated token account address for use
        const tokenATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
            mintKeypair.publicKey,
            publicKey // Use the public key from the web3 wallet
        );
        
        // Create a read-only Keypair object from the user's public key
        const userKeypair = new Keypair({ publicKey });

        const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
            .use(keypairIdentity(userKeypair)) // Corrected: use a Keypair object with the public key from the web3 wallet
            .use(
                bundlrStorage({
                    address: "https://devnet.bundlr.network",
                    providerUrl: "https://api.devnet.solana.com",
                    timeout: 60000,
                })
            );

      // Upload the image file to Bundlr and get the URI for the uploaded file
      const imageUri = await metaplex.storage().upload(imageFile); // Corrected: define and assign a value to the imageUri variable

      // upload metadata and get metadata uri (off chain metadata)
      const { uri } = await metaplex
          .nfts()
          .uploadMetadata({
              name: tokenName,
              description: description,
              image: imageUri, // Corrected: use the imageUri variable
          });

        console.log("metadata uri:", uri);
        
        // create NFT
        async function createNft(
            metaplex: Metaplex,
            uri: string
        ): Promise<NftWithToken> {
            const { nft } = await metaplex .nfts()
            .create({
                uri: uri,
                name: tokenName,
                sellerFeeBasisPoints: sellerFeeBasisPoints,
                symbol: symbol,
            });
        
            console.log(
                `Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${nft.address.toString()}?cluster=devnet`
            );
            
            return nft;
        }

        await createNft(metaplex, uri);
    }, [connection, publicKey]); // Make sure to include the connection and publicKey values in the dependency array

    return (
        <button onClick={onClick} disabled={!publicKey}>
            Create NFT!
        </button>
    );
};
```

`const userKeypair = new Keypair({ publicKey });`

I tried creating a keypair, but of course it did not work.

How do I create a transaction that when signed by the user starts the whole process, etc.?

Comment: Code is much easier to comprehend if it is properly indented (the indentation to reflect its structure).

Answer (score 5):

Don’t use the keypair identity in the frontend.

Used the wallet adapter identity instead https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#walletadapteridentity

import { walletAdapterIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';

const wallet = useWallet();
metaplex.use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet));